# Newly added contacts not visible in Android Emulator contacts

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I am adding new contacts as follows:-

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       String accountType = "test@gmail.com";
    values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType );
       String accountName = "com.google";
    values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName );
       Uri rawContactUri = getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);
       long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
       //Add contact number
       values.clear();
       values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
       values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
       values.put(Phone.NUMBER, "123456789");
       getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);

       //Type of phone number
       values.clear();
       values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
       values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
       values.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK);
       getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);

       //Add contact name
       values.clear();
       values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
       values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
       values.put(Data.DISPLAY_NAME, "First Second");
       getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Query runs successfully. But the added contacts are not visible in Android Emulator Contacts. Please help. Am I missing anything here.

Comment: Silly question: have you tried clicking the "View" menu in the Contacts app to see if there are any groups that you are not displaying?

Comment: did you get this resolved? I'm facing same problem