# Android: imported contacts are not visible

Tags: android, android-emulator, contactscontract, rawcontacts

I'm using Adnroid dev [SimpleSyncAdapter example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) to import cloud-based contacts into my application. The import runs fine, when I access `contracts2.db` in the emulator all contacts are there and `raw_contacts`, `data` and `contacts` tables seem to be properly populated. Here's a puzzler:

1. Newly imported contacts are not visible in the emulator. In fact when I click on "Contacts" it gives me message that `You don't have any contacts to display`
2. When I run the same import on my N1 phone I can only see imported info on pre-existing, matching contacts. If the contact is truly brand new it's not appearing in the contacts list.
3. If I manually add a contact and then run import then the information from my import gets merged into the manual contact by the same name (merged OK)
4. If I run import and then add contact manually this contact will not contain cloud-based info (no merge)

That makes me think that somehow sync between contacts and raw contacts is broken or mangled yet in contacts table I see `_id`, `name_raw_contact_id` and `lookup` columns clearly populated

Note: I found very similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502787/newly-added-contacts-not-visible-in-android-emulator-contacts) but unfortunately it has no answer

Comment: The main question is: what kind of contacts do you want to add? I mean: do you plan to use only standart Contact fields, or add some special for your type of contacts? If you want to create your own type of contacts you should create your own type of *Account*!

Comment: Yes, I do create account, thank you and import contacts into it. I don't know why you removed your updated answer since it had the solution: going to Contacts->Menu->Display options->Find account->Check "All Contacts" on the account

Comment: My answer was deleted by moderator.

Comment: Add the 2-nd part as new answer and I will accept it. The problem with original answer was that it wasn't legit answer until you extended it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find added contacts - open Contacts, press Menu button -> display options and enable your contacts type.